# Should the calculated values be placed in the database?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework, orm

In the project I use django, django-rest-framework, postgresql database + react/next on frontend. While developing the application, I came across a problem which, for lack of more experience, I am not able to solve on my own despite reading dozens of similar topics. In every topic one statement manifests itself: it depends.

**Keep the calculated totals in the database or calculate them with each query?**

The application is the simplest WMS (goods receipt, orders, goods release, invoices, etc.) with the ability to display reports with charts. The problem, however, is the volume of data totals I have never encountered.

1000 orders per day *
40 products on order *
25 work days *
12 months
= 12 000 000 rows

and from this data will be made calculations for example charts about profit, total revenue, amount of tax, etc.

Documents will not be changed practically ever, totals values also. However, I will read the values quite often, whether in the customer panel about invoices, orders or charts.... I'm afraid that recalculating these values every time will be a bad solution. On the other hand, these values used for later calculations are quite a lot ~20/30, maybe more.

I will certainly use pagination to display the data in the datagrid so the size of the data should not cause problems even when calculating the values. However, what about preparing the data for graphing. Let's give a check on the profit on a position within a year. Instead of simplistically filtering the pzitems for a given product and adding up the profit field, you will have to filter the pzitems for a given product and subtract the purchase price - selling price * discount from each item. **Will this work quickly or is it better to break the normalization of the database and use a simpler calculation.**

Below is a sample model (values done on the fly)

```
class DocumentProductInformation(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey("catalogues.Product", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default = 0)

    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    final_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    final_total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)

    gross_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    gross_total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    gross_final_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    gross_final_total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)

    discount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2, default=0.00, validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(1)])

    markup = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    margin = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    
    sales_tax_rate = models.ForeignKey("catalogues.TaxRate", related_name='%(class)s_sales_tax_rate', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    purchase_tax_rate = models.ForeignKey("catalogues.TaxRate", related_name='%(class)s_purchase_tax_rate', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    sales_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    sales_total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    sales_final_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    sales_final_total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)

    sales_gross_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    sales_gross_total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    sales_gross_final_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    sales_gross_final_total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)

    profit = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
```

Everything from above could be calculated from these fields below:

```
    product = models.ForeignKey("catalogues.Product", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    discount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2, default=0.00, validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(1)])
    markup = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    margin = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    sales_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
```

Comment: This question is really about DB design rather than Django, you should consider editing the question to remove things that make it specific to Django and add tags that would allow relevant SME's to discover your question. Also see [Bad Practice to Store Calculated Data in Database?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/202758/bad-practice-to-store-calculated-data-in-database) and [Storing vs calculating aggregate values](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/239/storing-vs-calculating-aggregate-values)

Comment: In a transactional database (orders, ...) it is best *not* to store redundant data to avoid inconsistencies. In a data warehouse, where you run analytical queries, you don't care. Build a second database for the analytical queries, into which you regularly load new data from the transactional database. There you pre-calculate and pre-aggregate whatever you can to make your analytical queries as fast as possible.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I read both topics mentioned before I wrote the question. In the end, I chose the solution of keeping any calculated values in the database. I did some tests and reading the calculated values makes a definite improvement in performance. The size of the database with 10 million rows is close to 1.5GB but the performance improvement makes up for it. In addition, it would be very difficult to filter the data.